# What is the main difference with picker api and OAuth JS-example

Tags: google-drive-api, google-picker

google picker api doesnt force the user to an OAuth dialog, no asking them to authorize the application to upload or request active user data. In the quickstart guide "https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-js" there is a simple example to upload a file for active user .The user must accept the application. What is the main difference with picker api and OAuth JS-example.
Can I write a code like picker api for active user
I want to upload and list active user drive data without using picker api

Answer (score 1):

The picker does two things which you can't do manually in a third-party application:

1. Uses cookie auth for the currently logged in Google user
2. Adds the file to the drive.file scope's opened with files, so an app with the file scope can access it.